# Android: BLE Bluetooth cannot connect to the device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am doing a scan for a device with a specific service UUID, the function scan, the device is found, and I connect.

I connect to the device every 2 minutes for 20 seconds.

Everything is working.

After a while the phone no longer connects to the device.

The device is found but unnamed.
I have to turn off the bluetooth and turn it on manually

Then it works again.

When I turn off and turn on the bluetooth programaticcally it doesn't work.

I guess it's a cache problem? ...

```
private fun startScan() {
        if (isScanning) return

        log("Start scanning for ${searchedDevice?.uuid.toString()}...")

        val builder: ScanFilter.Builder = ScanFilter.Builder()
        searchedDevice?.let {
            builder.setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(it.uuid.toString()))
        }

        val filter: ScanFilter = builder.build()
        val settings = ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .setReportDelay(200)
                .build()

        isScanning = true
        bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(listOf(filter), settings, scanCallback)
    }
```

onBacthScan:

```
override fun onBatchScanResults(results: MutableList<ScanResult>?) {
        super.onBatchScanResults(results)
        results?.firstOrNull()?.let {
            connectToPeripheral(it.device, connectionCompletion)
       }
    }
}
```

OnConnection:

```
override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
                super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)
```

I get status 133 what is?

**EDIT:**
Error 133 is:

```
case 0x0085:
return "GATT ERROR"; // Device not reachable
```

How to solve this error programaticcally